# Can't Configure Monitors on Linux Mint MSI Laptop With Nvidia Graphics

Tags: linux, graphics-card, linux-mint

First off: if any of this is confusing or missing info PLEASE comment and I'll happily clarify and/or add more info.

I've got a brand new MSI laptop with Linux Mint (17.1) installed on it.  It has an Nvidia GTX870m graphics card (and a built-in Intel one also).  It seems to be using the NVidia graphics drivers, but even though I have a second monitor plugged in, the "Monitor Preferences" dialog doesn't see it (even when I click "Detect Monitors".

I've tried installing the graphics drivers manually from NVidia, and automatically from the package nvidia-current, but neither one seems to work.  In fact, when I messed around with them too much I wound up killing my GUI, and nothing worked until I removed all nvidia* packages and then re-installed nvidia-current.

If I install nvidia-settings and run the NVidia settings program it works, but it only has two options on the left: Application Profiles and nvidia-settings Configuration.  Having used this program in the past, I would expect it to have many more options, including some for configuring my monitor, but strangely that's all I have.

Does anyone know how I can get my computer to recognize my monitor?  It can be via "Monitor Preferences", "Nvidia Settings", or any other program; I'm not picky :-)

P.S. When I first installed the drivers manually I was able to do `sudo service mdm stop` (from the `CTRL + F1` display) so that I could install the drivers. However, when I tried to reinstall them I found that same command no longer worked; when I tried to run it it would switch me to an all black screen with a single cursor.  So now I can't reinstall the manual drivers, because they require MDM to be off and I can't kill MDM without losing my command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I went in to the "Driver Manager" (from the menu) and saw that it was using the Noveau driver, so I changed it to "nvidia-331 (recommended)" and restarted, and after that my machine recognized both monitors.